# Unable to locate element though it is visible in WebPage

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am doing Selenium Webdriver automation using Java.

Please find the attached HTML extract of a web page http://1drv.ms/1CMtRxd and find the UI of the same http://1drv.ms/1JzXarv.

From the html, understand that all UI elements are constructed within a Table and the issue identified here is, unable to find the elements which are present in Right hand side table.

However, there is no issue on locating and using the elements present on left-hand side table within automation scripts.

Could you advise what is the difference between these two tables and why I’m unable to find the elements of Right hand side table during playback.

Also, could someone kindly help me to resolve this issue, please.

**Please find the code extract:**

**(Coded with Page Object Model)**

*In POM Class:*

```
@Test(description = "Test to Track the Order")
    public void searchOrder() throws Exception
    {
        SearchRequest searchReq = PageFactory.initElements(wd, SearchRequest.class);


        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        searchReq.enterTrackingID("161471");
        searchReq.clickSearchButton();

    }
```

*In Page Factory Class:*

```
public class SearchRequest
{

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "cpportal:searchByID")
    public WebElement   trackingID;

    public void enterTrackingID(String trackingID)
    {
        this.trackingID.clear();
        this.trackingID.sendKeys(trackingID);
    }

    @FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = " cpportal:j_idt56 ")
    public WebElement   search;

    public void clickSearchButton()
    {
        this.search.click();
    }
}
```

**Exception Thrown:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"cpportal:searchByID"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.12 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-27 00:00:10'
System info: host: 'inl-279930-1', ip: '10.13.136.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=cpportal:searchByID}
Session ID: 3c404b65-ba64-435d-8395-53c262eff602
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=37.0.2}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:393)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:37)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.clear(Unknown Source)
    at com.cgi.hqn.liveref.pageobjects.SearchRequest.enterTrackingID(SearchRequest.java:17)
    at com.cgi.hqn.liveref.test.CreateSOSL.searchOrder(CreateSOSL.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"cpportal:searchByID"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-27 00:00:10'
System info: host: 'inl-279930-1', ip: '10.13.136.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/SUBRAM~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5667416437314785176webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10271)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/SUBRAM~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5667416437314785176webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:603)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be an ajax element. Element is visible after a while.

What is the return value of-:

```
trackingID.isDisplayed();
```

This could be avoided by Implicit wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or by WebDriver wait

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(trackingID));
```

Hope that helps